# How to change archieve frequency of the media file in uploads folder for wordpress blog

Tags: uploads, archives, media, hosting

So far I can see my media file is divided into month and year as 2008/09 like directory. But I am getting concerned because I am currently hosting a community listing site that may incurr more than 1000 upload (which is the limit for most shared hosting for EACH directory). I realize recently that the shared site can not have more than 500,000 file/ file in combine. So I think it will be getting pretty limited after a while.

Anyone has solution for this issue in term of changing the archieve frequency maybe into every week instead of every month? I googled it but can never find a answer for it all at! Or...am I getting into a wrong direction?

Please help thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to set your weekly changing subdirs like, eg '2013/W35' /where 35 stands for 35th week of 2013 (`'W'` param of [php date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)),

you can use:

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'set_folder_to_week', 999);

function set_folder_to_week ( $upload_data ) {
  $y = date('Y');
  $w = 'W' . date('W');
  $subdir = "/$y/$w";
  $dir = $upload_data['basedir'] . $subdir;
  $url = $upload_data['baseurl'] . $subdir;
  return wp_parse_args(array('path'=>$dir, 'url'=>$url, 'subdir'=>$subdir), $upload_data);
}
```

All media uploaded before still continue to be founded and displayed correctly by wordpress (if they are retrieved using the proper wp functions).

Note that I've added `'W'` before week number in subdir name to avoid, on the first 12 weeks, url and path are the same of the standard /year/month path.

Comment: Thanks! Its seem really proceedable! I will try it out later! Appreciated :D ++